# BOOST CONVERTER Simulation Problems in Multisim

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, power-electronics, power-engineering, multisim

I am trying to simulate a boost converter to step up the voltage to 70V from a 40V source on the Load resistor. Based on the formula: Vout =Vs(1/1-D), i calculated the duty cycle to be 42.85% however when i attach a digital multimeter to the load resistor and set the duty cycle on the 10k resistor to 43.8%, i see only 14.23V on the output load. I am not sure what i am doing wrong and why the output voltage is so low. I have added the calculations for the rest of the components below: Note: This is my first time designing something like this that is why i started of with simulation first.

**Chosen Parameters:**

Input Voltage (Vs)=40V

Output Voltage (Vout)=70V

Switching Frequency(f):200khz

Output Ripple Voltage(Vo)=30mV

Output Power=20W

MOSFET:IRF510

DIODE:MUR415

1) **For Duty Cycle (As stated above):**

```
      Vout =Vs(1/1-D)

      70V=40V(1/1-D)

       D=42.85%
```

2)**Load Resistance (RL)**

```
    I=P/V=20/70=0.2857A

    RL=V/I=70/0.2857=245 ohms
```

**3)Filtering Capacitor:**

```
    C=D/RL*(30mV/70V)*f

    C=20.4uF, ROUNDED TO 22uF
```

4)Inductance:

```
   Lmin=D*(1-D)^2*R/2*f

  Lmin=85.71uH, 

however chosen value is L=2*Lmin=0.17142mH
```

**5) Series Resistance with inductor (Rs):**

```
  Vout=(Vs/1-D)(1/1+Rs*(RL(1-D)^2))

Solving for Rs i get Rs= 0 ohms however 2.2 ohms was chosen
```

[image: Boost Converter with Gate Driver]

[image]

Comment: What waveform is V1 producing?

Comment: I have added a transient analysis of the waveform, the V1 which is Vpulse is a ramp waveform that has peak value 4.95 volts (almost 5V)

Comment: So with R1 set to 43.8% below 10V the virtual op amp's output is continuously high (ie. 100% duty cycle), right?

Comment: if i understand your question correctly,  setting R1 at 43.8% yields 14.23V but if i increase to 53.8%, the voltage increases to 98.7V. The 43.8% is the duty cycle.

Comment: Duty cycle is the FET on/off ratio, which is not necessarily the same as the pot setting. When the pot is set to 43.8% what is the duty cycle of the waveform on the FET Gate? And what is the peak voltage of this waveform?

Comment: I am not sure how to determine the mosfets duty cycle, do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: Change V2 to 5V so it matches the sawtooth wave amplitude, and change the virtual comparator to a real one (eg. LM139) with 10V Vcc. Or change V1 to a square pulse waveform and adjust its on/off ratio, and drive the FET Gate directly from it.

Answer (score 2):

The formula you used to calculate the output voltage is this: -

\$Vout = \dfrac{Vs}{1-D}\$

However, it is only valid in continuous conduction mode (CCM) or, at the boundary between CCM and DCM. I suspect that you are operating somewhere between DCM and CCM and this will produce "odd" effects as your circuit-process crosses the boundary.

For instance, in DCM you will have a duty cycle that falls short of producing a current through the inductor that is always above zero amps (hence why it is called discontinuous mode). The Vout transfer function for this type of process has a much more complex formula than the one quoted above (for CCM) AND it involves the value of the load resistor.

In CCM there is always some current passing through the inductor but. the transfer function is different to that of DCM and, as a result, you can get a load-dependant step-change in output voltage when you cross the boundary.

Try operating at 100 kHz just to see what happens. This should be more consistent with operating in DCM and be less likely to cross the boundary into CCM.

These types of converters are power regulators and not voltage regulators. Energy is stoed in the inductor each half cycle and released on the next half cycle - they transfer energy based on duty cycle and that energy is proportional to duty cycle squared.

To regulate the output you need an analogue feedback system that dynamically adjusts the duty cycle in order to turn a power regulator into a voltage regulator.

Comment: So i changed the frequency of the pulse_voltage source to 100khz (10us) , however i get the following error because: 
"A simulation error has occurred. Would you like to run the Convergence Assistant to attempt to resolve this problem automatically? " Is this due to the rise and fall time of the pulse_voltage source, because i have it both set to 10us.

Comment: @user7187418 you need the rise time and fall times much shorter than 10 us. 10 us is the whole period of one cycle so 50 ns is more likely a better value.